# make relative links into absolute links, with simplehtmldom

Tags: php, html, parsing, preg-replace, simple-html-dom

I have a script that I'm trying to finish with [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
I can scrape the web-pages I want, the links are invalid. I want to make the links valid, so I’ve been trying different things, and not getting it to work.
I can get it to scrape, or to fix links from a previously saved page, but I cant seem to scrape the links, and fix the links so they reference the correct domain.

I might be misusing or misunderstanding how to use simplehtmldom's "save" function.

Here is what Ive got right now:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$file1 = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Electrician&l=maine";
$file2 = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Electronic&l=maine";
$file3 = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Electronics+Tech&l=maine"; 
$file4 = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Helpdesk&l=maine";
$file5 = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Trades&l=maine";
$SEARCH = array($file1, $file2, $file3, $file4, $file5);

//Fix links
$domain = "http://www.indeed.com";
$rep['/href="(?!https?:\/\/)(?!data:)(?!#)/'] = 'href="'.$domain;
$rep['/src="(?!https?:\/\/)(?!data:)(?!#)/'] = 'src="'.$domain;
$rep['/@import[\n+\s+]"\//'] = '@import "'.$domain;
$rep['/@import[\n+\s+]"\./'] = '@import "'.$domain;

//Find this: data-tn-component="organicJob"
//<div class="  row  result" id="p_a8a968e2788dad48" data-jk="a8a968e2788dad48" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting" data-tn-component="organicJob">

$html = new simple_html_dom();

for ($i = 0; $i<6; $i++)
{
    $html->load_file($SEARCH[$i]);

    foreach($html->find('div[data-tn-component="organicJob"]') as $div)
    {
      $str = $html->save($div);
      $output = preg_replace(array_keys($rep), array_values($rep), $str);
       echo  $output->innertext . "\n";
    }
}

?>
```

how can I scrape the pages, and fix the links to point to the correct domain?

Comment: I answered this same question a couple days ago. Do a search for simple-html-dom by newest and you will find my amswer.

Comment: Is There a way to have the other tags not stripped out?  I liked the former output, although the links are present now, the output is hard to read. 
im not sure if this constitutes a new question on my part.

Comment: I can't follow what you're asking so maybe a new question with some more context is a good idea.